# SQL server session tasks all waiting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that often completes in a fraction of a second (~200ms).

Sometimes it takes 10-13 seconds to complete. Doing `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` it shows:

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 231 ms,  elapsed time = 13772 ms.
```

This is the only thing active on this database instance. Furthermore, querying `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` it shows all tasks are waiting for CXPACKET but they are all waiting on each other, there is no task that isn't waiting.

```
0x0000000003D81048  54  28  4569    CXPACKET    0x000000021F3513B0  0x00000001F18CE088  54  39  exchangeEvent id=Pipe13f667850 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=13
0x00000001F18CE088  54  39  4569    CXPACKET    0x0000000209290080  0x00000000040BF048  54  30  exchangeEvent id=Pipe12d828cd0 WaitType=e_waitPipeNewRow nodeId=13
0x00000001F18CE2C8  54  24  8240    CXPACKET    0x00000001318BBBC0  0x000000000409A988  54  29  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1319daba0 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=11
0x00000001F18CE748  54  30  8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001F6CFF960  0x000000021D1182C8  54  21  exchangeEvent id=Pipeea331060 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=6
0x000000000409A988  54  29  8243    CXPACKET    0x00000001F5F373B0  0x00000001F18CE088  54  39  exchangeEvent id=Port8025e600 WaitType=e_waitPortClose nodeId=13
0x000000021D1182C8  54  21  8241    CXPACKET    0x00000001FA1B5BC0  0x000000000409A988  54  29  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1f5e6cee0 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=11
0x000000021D118748  54  25  8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001E4D71960  0x000000021D1182C8  54  21  exchangeEvent id=Pipe12d890a00 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=6
0x00000000040B4E08  54  0   8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001E9206890  0x000000021D118748  54  25  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1ee39e800 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=1
0x00000000040B4E08  54  0   8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001E9206890  0x000000013F684508  54  27  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1ee39e800 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=1
0x00000000040B4E08  54  0   8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001E9206890  0x0000000090DB0BC8  54  32  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1ee39e800 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=1
0x00000000040B4E08  54  0   8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001E9206890  0x00000000A5800508  54  31  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1ee39e800 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=1
0x00000000040B4E08  54  0   8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001E9206890  0x00000001F195E508  54  28  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1ee39e800 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=1
0x00000000040B4E08  54  0   8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001E9206890  0x0000000083E90BC8  54  26  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1ee39e800 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=1
0x00000000040B4E08  54  0   8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001E9206890  0x00000001E7A32748  54  29  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1ee39e800 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=1
0x00000000040B4E08  54  0   8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001E9206890  0x00000001F18CE748  54  30  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1ee39e800 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=1
0x00000000040B4BC8  54  32  8242    CXPACKET    0x00000001EF9C53B0  0x00000001F18CE088  54  39  exchangeEvent id=Port8025e600 WaitType=e_waitPortClose nodeId=13
0x00000001E7A322C8  54  18  8241    CXPACKET    0x0000000221DC3BC0  0x000000000409A988  54  29  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1e5a45ad0 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=11
0x00000001E7A32748  54  29  8236    CXPACKET    0x000000021CEE9960  0x000000021D1182C8  54  21  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1ecd3a5c0 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=6
0x00000000040BF048  54  30  4569    CXPACKET    0x000000012FA3C290  0x000000021D1182C8  54  21  exchangeEvent id=Pipe131a606b0 WaitType=e_waitPipeNewRow nodeId=11
0x00000000040BF4C8  54  22  8240    CXPACKET    0x00000001F50D3BC0  0x000000000409A988  54  29  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1319daac0 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=11
0x0000000090DB0BC8  54  32  8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001E67D7960  0x000000021D1182C8  54  21  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1eed8c5b0 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=6
0x00000000041E8988  54  27  8243    CXPACKET    0x00000000A55573B0  0x00000001F18CE088  54  39  exchangeEvent id=Port8025e600 WaitType=e_waitPortClose nodeId=13
0x000000013F684088  54  17  8241    CXPACKET    0x00000001FA8FFBC0  0x000000000409A988  54  29  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1319db030 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=11
0x000000013F684508  54  27  8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001E9309960  0x000000021D1182C8  54  21  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1ecd3b600 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=6
0x0000000004203048  54  26  8235    CXPACKET    0x00000001007FE290  0x000000021D1182C8  54  21  exchangeEvent id=Pipe202f84ea0 WaitType=e_waitPipeNewRow nodeId=11
0x00000000A5800088  54  19  8241    CXPACKET    0x00000001F1DD5BC0  0x000000000409A988  54  29  exchangeEvent id=Pipe12ed0b0e0 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=11
0x00000000A5800508  54  31  8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001F3D2F960  0x000000021D1182C8  54  21  exchangeEvent id=Pipea2b3a570 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=6
0x000000000421C988  54  25  8243    CXPACKET    0x00000001F345B3B0  0x00000001F18CE088  54  39  exchangeEvent id=Port8025e600 WaitType=e_waitPortClose nodeId=13
0x00000001F195E088  54  23  8241    CXPACKET    0x00000001EA6E3BC0  0x000000000409A988  54  29  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1f3c22f70 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=11
0x00000001F195E508  54  28  8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001F4945960  0x000000021D1182C8  54  21  exchangeEvent id=Pipea2b3a400 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=6
0x0000000083E902C8  54  31  8242    CXPACKET    0x00000000E834D3B0  0x00000001F18CE088  54  39  exchangeEvent id=Port8025e600 WaitType=e_waitPortClose nodeId=13
0x0000000083E90748  54  20  8241    CXPACKET    0x00000001E7A23BC0  0x000000000409A988  54  29  exchangeEvent id=Pipe12ed0b220 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=11
0x0000000083E90BC8  54  26  8236    CXPACKET    0x00000001F0C6B960  0x000000021D1182C8  54  21  exchangeEvent id=Pipe1301e64a0 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=6
```

I am tearing my hair out here, and I suspect it's something due to machine configuration rather than the query itself. It *is* doing a lot of joins in the query, but nothing that should cause such difference in execution time. The plan is always the same every time.

Is there anything I can watch for in performance monitor or similar that might give me a clue to what is delaying the execution sometimes?

Comment: You might want to read up on [CXPacket wait](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/08/what-is-the-cxpacket-wait-type-and-how-do-you-reduce-it/). You _might_ need to increase cost threshold.

Comment: Actually, I would set the MAXDOP to a much smaller setting (it's probably at 0 right now). First, put it to a small amount that resides in a single numa node, such as 4 or 8. You're parallel queries are stomping on each other.

Comment: Yes, OPTION(MAXDOP 1) Seemed to fix the problem. It's concerning that parellism can end up freezing itself but I'm relieved the issue is fixed. Feel free to type up a full answer and I can accept.

Comment: I wouldn't turn off parallelism (maxdop 1) but I'd keep it much less than all possible cpus. It can look like it's freezing itself because it's trying to schedule ALL of the cpus at the SAME time across multiple queries. This causes massive blocking and waiting, especially as the number of cpus increases. This is why I would never put the maxdop higher than the amount of cpus in a single numa node.